# Gulp : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: gulp

I have a project which builds successfully on an Apple Mac but produces the following error when trying to run a gulp task on Windows:

```
project\node_modules\.bin\gulp:2
basedir=$(dirname $(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g'))
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "gulp": "node node_modules/.bin/gulp",
    "build-local": "npm run gulp build-local",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~2.0.x",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.6.x",
    "gulp-live-server": "^0.0.31",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.x",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~2.5.x",
    "gulp-stylelint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~2.1.x",
```

It it helps I'm using an old version of Node (10.0.0) because the project is quite dated